# How to send multidimensional array as data using array key in codeigniter?

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter, multidimensional-array, controller

I just want to send some data as array from view to controller using a array key. But can not solve this following problem whenever it comes to send multidimensional array.

**Here is my controller**

```
public function all_products(){
        $data['ls'] = $this->product_details('product1');
        $data['ws'] = $this->product_details('product2');
        $data['wr'] = $this->product_details('product3');
        $this->load->view('view_page', $data);
}

public function product_details($key){
        $data['g'] = // Some rows from database
        $data['p'] = // Some rows from database
        $data['o'] = // Some rows from database
        return $data;
}
```

After that, if I print the data key, the output showing in view

```
<?=print_r("ls")?>
// ls1 [Output]
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You only need this in your function:

```
public function product_details($key)
{
  $this->db->select()->from('mydb')->where('id', $key);
  return $this->db->get()->row();
}
```

And retrived it in your Controller:

```
public function all_products()
{
  $data['product1'] = $this->Product_model->product_details($key1);
  $data['product2'] = $this->Product_model->product_details($key2);
  $data['product3'] = $this->Product_model->product_details($key1);

  $this->load->view->('product', $data);
}
```

In your view:

```
<p>Name of Product 1: <?php echo $product1->product_name; ?></p>
<p>Name of Product 2: <?php echo $product2->product_name; ?></p>
<p>Name of Product 3: <?php echo $product3->product_name; ?></p>
```

Comment: Thank you for your effort. But sorry, this is not my solution. You have modified my `product_details($key)` function and sends only one array. But I need to send multiple array from this function.

Comment: @WebDevRon, could you be more specific about what are you going to do? specially your model, just give some example of your database so you assume to have multidimensional array

Comment: Please look at my question. `product_details($key)` is in my `controller` not in model.

Comment: @WebDevRon, You say `...send some data as array from view to controller using a array key..`. Could you show your code in your view? I may update my answer and try my best to solve it.